# ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection ValidateOnBuild not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-5

I have a project in .NET 5 with RazorPages, I set this code to validate the Dependency Injection in the Progam.cs file:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseDefaultServiceProvider(options =>
            {
                options.ValidateOnBuild = true;
                options.ValidateScopes = true;
            })....
```

I forgot to register the service that is injected into my page, so I would have expected that when I try to start the app an error page would show this kind of problem, but I don't understand why it doesn't happen, because for example in case I don't register ILocalizerService this happens:
This is my RazorPage:

```
public class SignupModel : IdentityPageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public Models.Account.Signup Signup { get; set; }

    private readonly CustomUserManager _userManager;
    private readonly ILogger<SignupModel> _logger;
    private readonly INcsService _ncsService;

    public SignupModel(CustomUserManager userManager, 
        ILogger<SignupModel> logger,
        INcsService ncsService) : base(localizerService)
    {
        Guard.Against.Null(userManager, nameof(userManager));

        Guard.Against.Null(logger, nameof(logger));
        Guard.Against.Null(ncsService, nameof(ncsService));
        
        _userManager = userManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _ncsService = ncsService;
    }

    // Other code....
}
```

This is my service:

```
[PublicAPI]
public class NcsService : INcsService
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public NcsService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    // Other code...
}
```

I have only registered IHttpClientFactory but not INcsService interface and implementation:

```
services.AddHttpClient(nameof(NcsService), client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ncsSettings.BaseUri);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-functions-key", ncsSettings.ApiKey);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-app-name", "TSID");

}).AddHeaderPropagation(options =>
{
    options.Headers.Add("x-request-id");
    options.Headers.Add("x-correlation-id");
})
.AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root of the issue is Microsoft's default `IComponentActivator` implementation (the [DefaultComponentActivator](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/Components/Components/src/DefaultComponentActivator.cs)). The Component Activator is in control of creating your Razor Pages, but the built-in behavior does not request those pages from the built-in container. Instead, it just creates them [using Activator.CreateInstance](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/Components/Components/src/DefaultComponentActivator.cs#L21).

This means that Blazor does *not* register your pages in the built-in container and because of that, the page will not be part of the container's verification process.

This is, IMO, a design flaw in Blazor, because it is well known, and well understood, that in case you are using a DI Container, you should let *all* your application components go through the container pipeline. That's the only way that the container can give you a reasonable amount of certainty about the validity of your application components.

Blazor, however, is not the only part of the ASP.NET Core framework where this happens. ASP.NET MVC Controllers, for instance, by default aren't registered in the container, and aren't resolved from the container. This is configurable though, but since this is not the default behavior, the `ValidateOnBuild` gives a false sense of security.

Other containers might have a more sensible default. Simple Injector, for instance, (the container that I maintain) contains extension methods that *always* register all MVC controllers up front. And with its Blazor integration, [similar things](https://simpleinjector.org/blazor) happen.

If you stick with the built-in container, it would be good to ensure all components are resolved from the container. With MVC this is easy, because you can simply call `AddControllersAsServices`. With Blazor, unfortunately, this is much more difficult, because there exists no such method as `AddComponentsAsServices`. This means that you have to create a custom `IComponentActivator` that calls back into the container. But still, you'll likely have to fallback to the original behavior using `Activator.CreateInstance` for all Blazor Components that are created by Microsoft, because it might be much harder to find and register them using reflection. For inspiration on how to create such custom Component Activator and register your application Blazor components, take a look at the code presented [here](https://simpleinjector.org/blazor).

Comment: Hi Steven, first of all thanks for the answer, actually mine is not a Blazor application, but a simple application with RazorPages, which I believe as you specify is based on "MVC". I was always using SimpleInjector and I am well aware of the verification functionality it has, unfortunately the thing I still don't like is that currently it is not possible to completely replace the Microsoft container with it

Comment: @pampua84. Simple Injector will never replace the built-in container. It will always live side-by-side.